# Using toChar to output a date in W3C XML Schema xs:dateTime type format

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm trying to convert `sysdate` using `toChar` to the following format:
`2006-11-20T17:10:02+01:00`

From this format:
`16/08/2012 13:40:59`

Is there a standard way of doing this?

I've tried using the `toChar` to specific the `T` part as a string but it doesn't appear to be working.

Thanks in advance

Jezzipin

EDIT:

I've tried Nicholas' solution however as I mention above, I need to use sysdate. I've used the following select query:

```
    select to_char(to_timestamp_tz(sysdate-365, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss TZH:TZM') from dual;
```

However, this returns:

```
     0012-08-16T00:00:00 +01:00
```

which is incorrect as it should be 2012-08-16T00:00:00 +01:00

Comment: Why you do need to use `sysdate`? Why [`systimestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions192.htm) can't be used as you're requiring timezone information anyway ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try:**

```
 select to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy-mm-dd') || 'T' || to_char(sysdate,'hh24:mi:ss') || sessiontimezone
from dual;
```

**Returns:**

2013-08-16T13:00:51+00:00

Answer (score 1):

To display `sysdate` in the format that contains timezone information you need to do a series of conversions:

1. Convert `sysdate` to string literal using `to_char()` function.
2. Convert string literal to timestamp with tome zone using `to_timestamp_tz()` function.
3. And finally, convert the final result back to string literal using `to_char()`.

as follows:

```
 select to_char(
                to_timestamp_tz(
                                 to_char(sysdate - 365, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
                                , 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
                , 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss TZH:TZM'
               ) as res
  from dual
```

Result:

```
RES
--------------------------
2012-08-16T17:29:28 +04:00
```

You can include string literal in the format mask enclosing it with double quotes.

Comment: I need to use this in combination with sysdate as mentioned above. I've therefore done the following: select to_char(to_timestamp_tz(sysdate-365, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss TZH:TZM') from dual; however this returns 0012-08-16T00:00:00 +01:00 which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The value with 'T' is called [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), also known as 'XS:DateTime' or 'XSD:DateTime' or 'XML Schema DateTime'. 
Note that Oracle's sessiontimezone command can return not only '-04:00' but also a value like 'America/Los_Angeles' (depending on the db settings), which is probably not something you want.
There is also a replacement required since TZ_OFFSET returns \0 - terminated string. So this should work:

```
create or replace function to_iso8601 (datetime_in in date) return varchar is 
begin
    return to_char(datetime_in, 'yyyy-mm-dd') || 'T' || to_char(datetime_in,'hh24:mi:ss') || replace(TZ_OFFSET(DBTIMEZONE),chr(0));
end;
/
select to_iso8601(sysdate) from dual;
```

result:

```
2014-11-03T16:53:45-04:00
```